# Why doesn't whatsapp read my og:tags as it should?

Tags: javascript, html, facebook-opengraph, whatsapp, share-open-graph

So I have a webpage that autogenerate og:tags for link preview on facebook, whatsapp etc. but whatsapp apparently can't scrape them. It works good on facebook but not on whatsapp. In whatsapp it just gives me this error message (see pictures. only somtimes, the other times nothing shows up) like the site has an error (which it doesnt have, you can access the page like any other page).

The og:tags are also correct in the  tag in the site's source code.

Does anyone know why it is like this?

[image]

[image]

Comment: HTTP 500 is quite self-explanatory. Your website crashed when WhatsApp made a request for it. You should fix that.

Comment: Yes but you can still access the page as any other page. Its just that whatsapp for some reason is thinking that the website is down or that the page could not be found.

Comment: Check your server logs.

Answer (score 0):

Did you post these links in WhatsApp already at a time, when they did not have og-data? Then you can try to delete all that links in the WhatsApp-Group-Media/Link-List and repost. That works for me with a similar issue with og-data in WhatsApp.

Comment: This is the link to one of the pages that doesnt work https://www.rototilt.com/en-gb/about-us/. Im not really sure what you mean by "WhatsApp-Group-Media/Link-List"

Comment: og:url ist not https. og:image is not available

Comment: With WhatsApp-Group-Media/Link-List i mean the List with all Links for that WA-Chat or WA-Group-Chat. Go to Group-Info and search for Links. You can then delete that Link with wrong Preview after you update them and repost it

Comment: Aha okay, I did  those things but it didnt help of some reason. It still says "500 - internal server error" or "404 - File or directory not found". It bugs me that the website crashes when whatsapp is making a request to it.

Comment: Did you clear/delete that link in your WathApp-Chat-Link-List? That's kind of a local cache. If i post that link in a WA-Group it works, in spite of the og:url still points to http. But you should update that also...